# How do I combine following two queries which return a users most recent x and most recent y?

Tags: postgresql

This query returns the most recent x used:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (usersq1.id) usersq1.id AS user_id,
usersq1.name,
x_id AS last_x_used, started_at AS x_date
FROM usersq1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tripsq1
ON usersq1.id = user_id
ORDER BY usersq1.id;
```

It returns a table that looks similar to this:

```
 user_id |        name         | last_x_used    | x_date
---------+---------------------+----------------+------------
    1001 | Makeda Mosser       |            113 | 2017-06-07
    1002 | Libbie Luby         |            115 | 2017-06-09
    1003 | Linn Loughran       |            103 | 2017-06-03
    1004 | Natacha Ned         |            104 | 2017-06-04
    1005 | Lorrine Lunt        |            105 | 2017-06-05
    1006 | Tami Tineo          |            106 | 2017-10-06
    1007 | Delisa Deen         |            107 | 2017-10-07
    1008 | Mimi Miltenberger   |            108 | 2017-10-08
    1009 | Seth Sneller        |            109 | 2017-10-09
    1010 | Rickie Rossi        |            110 | 2017-10-10
    1011 | Jenise Jeanbaptiste |            101 | 2017-06-01
    1012 | Genia Glatz         |            101 | 2017-06-02
    1013 | Onita Oddo          |            101 | 2017-06-03
    1014 | Dario Dreyer        |            102 | 2017-06-04
    1015 | Toby Trent          |                |
```

This query returns the most recent y used:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (usersq1.id) usersq1.id AS user_id,
usersq1.name,
tripsq1.id AS trip_id, y_id  AS last_y_used, started_at AS y_date
FROM usersq1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tripsq1
ON usersq1.id = user_id
WHERE coupon_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY usersq1.id, y_id DESC;
```

It returns a table that looks similar to this:

```
 user_id |        name         | last_Y      | Y_date
---------+---------------------+-------------+-------------
    1001 | Makeda Mosser       |           4 | 2017-06-02
    1002 | Libbie Luby         |           7 | 2017-06-02
    1011 | Jenise Jeanbaptiste |           5 | 2017-06-30
    1012 | Genia Glatz         |           6 | 2017-07-02
```

I would like to write a query which results in showing a user_id, user_name, last_x_used, x_date, last_y_used, y_date

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are you sure your queries return the *most recent* x and y? Doesn't seem so to me

Comment: @giorgiga wondering what makes you say that? Still learning here so feel free to take me to school

Comment: Well there is nothing that tells the db to select the *most recent* `tripsq1` (no `order by started_at  desc`, nor `select max(started_at)`, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to take the time to understand or optimize your queries.  Just stick them in a subquery and do a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (usersq1.id) 
      usersq1.id AS user_id,
      usersq1.name,
      x_id       AS last_x_used, 
      started_at AS x_date
   FROM usersq1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tripsq1
     ON usersq1.id = user_id
   ORDER BY usersq1.id 
) sub1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (usersq1.id) 
      usersq1.id AS user_id,
      usersq1.name,
      tripsq1.id AS trip_id, 
      y_id       AS last_y_used, 
      started_at AS y_date
   FROM usersq1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tripsq1
     ON usersq1.id = user_id
   WHERE coupon_id IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY usersq1.id, y_id DESC
) sub2 USING(user_id);
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're right… OUTER JOIN necessary (my bad)

Comment: If the OP accepts it, then you're right...let's wait for feedback +1.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have answered as I don't really have the time to give it considerable thought.  Only answered because no one else did so he can get back to doing what he's doing.  An ideal answer would probably also clean up those subqueries — it looks like a more efficient query is possible.

Comment: This will work. Sounds like I need to work on my efficiency.